# Google Chrome OS dev accounts

Tags: google-chrome-os

I've [made](http://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/chromium-os/building-chromium-os/build-instructions) it run under a VM, but now it is just a browser, no apps. When I`m trying to access the menu it asks for a google.com domain account. Where do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](http://www.beingmanan.com/wp/2009/11/chrome-os-demo-videos-details/):

> Since you need a google.com email id
>   to access applications you don’t have
>   access to any of that as the general
>   public doesn’t get @google.com email
>   id. Chances are in later builds this
>   will open up for @gmail.com accounts.

Comment: I read somewhere that you get three google gmail accounts when you sign up, reserved just for you, including  a google.com one... will follow up with a link...

Comment: @paulhomebus I wasn't aware of that, looking forward to your follow up.

Comment: According to this link one of the multiple addresses is googlemail.com
http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/gmail-email-alias-two-separate-gmail-address/2388/

Comment: Another article on multiple gmail addresses....
http://blog.waveadept.com/2010/google-gives-you-three-free-email-addresses-alongside-gmail/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+WaveAdeptBlog+(WaveAdept+Blog)
It does look like the @google.com address may be reserved tho... still checking

Comment: @paulhomebus can't be googlemail.com, googlemail.com is assigned to UK folks as gmail.com cannot be used there because of some litigation (AFAIK )